# Use JDO in Android

Tags: android, jdo

I've tried to find any info on that subject; can't find anything. Strikes me as odd, since <kbd>JDO</kbd> sounds like the kind of thing smartphones should be very good at doing.

*Do you know if <kbd>JDO</kbd> is possible at all on Android devices, natively, or with external apps/libraries?*

Comment: Why are you trying to do that ? Should your database be on your phone ? May be you should decide the type of database to use on the phone before deciding the technology and then attempting to find a database that suits it. This way, you may find the database that suits you along with it's api. Good luck.